# unable to set value to formgroup inside the sub object

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to set value to sub group but getting error. below is my code

```js
let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
'name': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].name),
'category': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].category)
}));
let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(this.fb.group({
name: this.users[0].name,
displayOrder: this.users[0].displayOrder,
sort: new FormGroup({ 
type:new FormControl(),
format: new FormControl()
}),
data: dataArr
}));
```

I tried to set value to **sort object having type and format**. but unable to set. my json object is

```js
[{"name":"manu","displayOrder":1,"sort":{
"type":"first","format":"normal"
},"data":[{"category":"electrical","name":"ele"}]},{"name":"divya","displayOrder":1,"data":[{"category":"tech","name":"ea_tcv"}]}]
```

screenshot of the form;

[image]

How to set the value to sort object?

[My code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-current?file=app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question correctly but if you need to set values to the Sort object, you could simply pass the corresponding fields from the data object to the FormControl constructor:

```
patch() {
    let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
    dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
       'name': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].name),
       'category': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].category)
    }));

      let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
      formArr.push(this.fb.group({
          name: this.users[0].name,
          displayOrder: this.users[0].displayOrder,
          sort: new FormGroup({ 
              type:new FormControl(this.users[0].sort.type), // pass your values here
              format: new FormControl(this.users[0].sort.format)
          }),
          data: dataArr
      }));
}
```